# How do I extract array values from hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures, highcharts

I'm struggling with a data structures in Ruby.

I have:

```
answers = [
    {"val"=>["6"], "comment"=>["super"], "qid"=>["2"]},
    {"val"=>["3"], "comment"=>[""], "qid"=>["1"]},
    {"val"=>["7"], "comment"=>[""], "qid"=>["4"]},
    {"val"=>["5", "6"], "comment"=>["supera", "hmm"], "qid"=>["1", "2"]},
    {"val"=>["5", "9"], "comment"=>["super", "asdf"], "qid"=>["1", "5"]}
]
```

I need the following arrays for the qid's, which should be unique, all over the hashes:

```
["2","1","4","5"] # note, value 2 exists two times and value 1, 3 times
```

The corresponding values should be summarized and divided through number of counts:

```
["12","13","7","9"] will be: ["6","4.3","7","9"] # 12/2 and 13/3
```

The comments should be summarized as well:

```
[["super","hmm"],["","supera","super"],[""],["asdf"]]
```

I'm wondering if it's cool to put it together in an hash?

So far I have:

```
a = Hash.new(0)
  answers.each.map { |r| r }.each do |variable|
    variable["qid"].each_with_index do |var, index|
        #a[var] << { :count => a[var][:count] += 1 }
        #a[var]["val"] += variable["val"][index]
        #a[var]["comment"] = a[var]["comment"].to_s + "," + variable["comment"][index].to_s
    end   
  end
```

I'm trying to generate data for [Highcharts Demo - Basic bar](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic). The gem is [LazyHighCharts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts)

Any Ideas? Suggestions?

**Edit:**

Maybe I have to explain again the structure:
there are questions id's (qid), each of them has a value and a comment, I am trying to calculate the average of the "val" hashes

Comment: I don't follow your logic for the corresponding values. How are those being calculated? Are the comments in any order too?

Comment: yes, the order is all over the same in the hash, there are different qid's ind different hashes.

if I ask you for all comments of qid = 2? you get "super" and "hmm" right? 
the values of qid=2 are "6" and "6" divided by count(qid) (over all hashes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I understand what you're shooting for...

```
# lets create a hash to store the data
# such that my_data[qid][0] => value sum
#           my_data[qid][1] => number of times qid appeared
#           my_data[qid][2] => comments array

my_data = {}

# go through answers and fill my_data out

answers.each do |h|
    for i in 0...h["qid"].length
        qid = h["qid"][i]

        # awesome ruby syntax that will set my_data[qid] 
        # only if it hasn't already been set using "or-equals" operator
        my_data[qid] ||= [0, 0, []] 

        my_data[qid][0] += h["val"][i].to_i # add value
        my_data[qid][1] += 1                # increment count
        my_data[qid][2] << h["comment"][i]  # add comment
    end
 end

# how to get the data out for qid of "2"

my_data["2"][0].to_f / my_data["2"][1] # => 6
my_data["2"][2]                        # => ["super", "hmm"]

# and we could do this process for any qid, or all qids by iterating over
# my_data. we could even build the arrays in your OP

qids = []
average_values = []
comments = []

my_data.each do |k, v|
    qids << k
    average_values << v[0].to_f / v[1]
    comments << v[2]
end

# qids           => ["2", "1", "4", "5"]
# average_values => [6, 4.3, 7, 9]
# comments       => [["super", hmm"] ["", "supera", "super"], [""], ["asdf"]]
```

Comment: there is always a question, a value and a comment which belongs together, the first element is 12 because there is a question id 2, with value 6 (first row) and a second time qid appears on the pre-last line, again with value 6, if you count them together you get 12/2

Comment: `{"val"=>["6"], "comment"=>["super"], "qid"=>["2"]}`  means: question id: 2, value: 6, comment: super
they are together

Comment: Updated my answer. I think I understand what you were shooting for.

Comment: you made my day! I moved the `do` before the iterator and it worked! great! thank you, but 1. whats the difference between `.each` and `.each_pair` I thought with `each` you only get one iterator? 2. is it necessary to initialize the hash with all "keys" like `[0, 0, []]` ? 3. and it is no possible to mix hash keys like `my_data["5".to_s][0.to_i]` ?

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! Sorry about the "do"--emabarrasing. 1) I believe `each_pair` is an alias for `each` meaning they aren't different. 2) Yes, we have to initailize the keys, otherwise they are `nil`. You could make it so all keys have default value using the new method like so: `my_data = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [0, 0, []] }` 3) Yes, your hash can have keys of different types

Comment: Just in case this isn't clear, when you call `my_data["2"][0]` only the `"2"` is the key. It just so happens that `my_data["2"]` returns an array so we can say `my_data["2"][0]` to access the zeroeth element in that array.

Comment: ok! got it, almost, i'm unsure about this key thing: basically there are no nested keys? can we do: my_data[:key]["2"] as an example?

Comment: No you can not. A key can be any arbitrary object, but only a single object. If you wanted the effect of nested keys, there are ways to achieve that. One way is to use an array: `my_data[[:key, "2"]]`, but remember the key is still a single object--the array `[:key, "2"]`. Also, it's important to note that my answer has nothing to do with nested keys or anything like that. In my answer `my_data` takes the desired `qid` as the key and the value for any `qid` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

For `qid`:

```
result_qid = answers.map{|i| i['qid']}.flatten.uniq!
#["2", "1", "4", "5"]

result_qid = answers.map{|i| i['qid']}.flatten.group_by{|i| i}.map{|i,j| [i,j.length]}
#[["2", 2], ["1", 3], ["4", 1], ["5", 1]]
```

I can't figure out the logic for corresponding values!

Comment: thanks, there is always a qid (question id) a comment and a score, which belongs together, how can I be sure with uniq to keep the values together?

Answer (score 0):

If storing data in Hash is so restricted, you can define a new Class and manage data processing in that Class. I would have something like this:

```
class AnswerParser
  def intialize(answers)
    #your implementation here
  end

  def qids
    #your implementation here
  end

  def comments
    #your implementation here
  end
  ...

end

#usage
parser = AnswerParser.new(anwsers)
qids = parser.qids
...
```

With this, you can separate the codes for easier testing and usability.

Hope this helps.